# Blazor render component dynamically on route change

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, razor-pages

In Blazor, would it be possible to listen to routing events and (instead of navigating to a new page), eg. based on response from a rest api, dynamically render components on the page you're on? Without building a custom router?

Comment: I think not, you can get Navigation Events but you can not cancel ist: https://blazor-university.com/routing/detecting-navigation-events/

Comment: So, if someone tried to go to /counter you would stay on / and call an api to find out what component(s) to render? You could just have one @​page with route parameter(s) - I suppose, but you would need to override BuildRenderTree to add dynamic components

Comment: @MisterMagoo - I would stay on the page, yes, but the route should still update. Imagine an SPA where you get the content and site hierarchy provided by a rest api. The Blazor application would not know the possible routes, but the rest api would provide information as to what component the Blazor app should render for a given route. (This is the pattern you would use when building an SPA against a headless CMS in say ReactJS or Vue).

Comment: I would just build the custom router

Comment: I've come to that conclusion myself.